# MacOS Mojave ISO

Tags: macos, iso-image

I want to ask you about MacOS iso. I am wonder how is possible to download full version of MacOS Mojave? I thought it is locked system. My IT teacher dowloaded it from somebody Google Disk for demonstration purpose for students - he run it on virtual machine because system is bound to Apple's hardware only.

But Apple doesn't offer official ISOs so that seems strange for me to get full MacOS...
So how it is possible to get MacOS iso?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it was copied from a downloaded image before upgrading (using an older version of Mac OS). E.g. you can download a new version, then choose to install it "later", and then grab it from wherever it's been downloaded on disk

Answer (score 3):

Apple only distributes full macOS installers via their App Store - available to anyone already running macOS, or from Internet Recovery, which is built-into the firmware of all Macs.

There is no need to make it available by any other method, as it isn't licensed for any hardware that can't already access it legitimately.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the head up, you are totally right.  Please find the full answer below.

Convert MacOS Mojave installer into ISO format. Follow the steps below.

---

**1. Download MacOS Mojave Installer**

The first thing to do is to download the installer and save locally. Basically you have to download 3 DMG files and need to tweak them into a single `.app` file. It's complicated and hacky.

You don't need to do that manually, some guys has created a tool for us to work on this automatically.

Download this [macOS Mojave Installer Patch Tool](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/).

Make sure to follow the instructions on that page to get the final `macOS Mojave Installer.app` file, putting it somewhere, for example: `~/Downloads/Install macOS Mojave.app`

**2. Convert into ISO file**

This part requires you know how to execute commands from Terminal.

1. Create a virtual disk for installation media (DMG file).

   ```
   hdiutil create -o /tmp/Mojave -size 8000m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
   ```

   It will create a virtual disk image at `tmp/Mojave`.
2. Mount the disk.

   ```
   hdiutil attach /tmp/Mojave.dmg -noverify -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
   ```

   The virtual disk image is attached to mount into `/Volumes/install_build`.
3. Write the installer into mount point.

   ```
   sudo /Downloads/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/install_build
   ```

   The `createinstallmedia` is the tool packed into the `Install macOS Mojave.app` file that we've downloaded from all above.

   Make sure to use correct path and execute command with `sudo` like above.
4. Unmount the installer app.

   After executing command at step 3, it will automatically mount the app file, so now you need to eject it for step 5 below.
5. Save DMG info ISO format,

   ```
   hdiutil convert /tmp/Mojave.dmg -format UDTO -o ~/Downloads/Mojave
   ```

   After this command, you will see this file `~/Downloads/Mojave.cdr`.
6. Change file extension to ISO,

   ```
   mv ~/Downloads/Mojave.cdr ~/Downloads/Mojave.iso
   ```

   After this you have the file `~/Downloads/Mojave.iso`.

   You can use this file to create a bootable USB stick or install macOS Mojave on virtualization servers like VMware or VirtualBox.

   Also, clean up the temporary virtual disk image to save spaces if needed.

The original source is here: (https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/a9twye/mac_os_1014_mojave_vmware_15_diy_guide_no_3rd/).

This article has been copied from here: (https://blog.petehouston.com/download-and-convert-macos-mojave-installer-into-iso-file/).